# PHP, skip first and last line of a text file using fgets

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how to skip the first and last line of a text file when I'm reading it while using `fgets()`. The first line could be solved with an `if(!$firstLine)`, but I'm not sure how to ignore the last line or if my solution for ignoring the first line is the best choice.

Comment: file() puts each line in to an array, making what you want to do easy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
fgets($file); //Ignore the first line
$line = fgets($file);
$next = fgets($file); 
while ($next !== false) { //check the line after the one you will process next.  
                //This way, when $next is false, then you still have one line left you could process, the last line.
    //Do Stuff
    $line = $next;
    $next = fgets($file);
}
```

Comment: if last line of file would be `'0'` or will be empty it will break too early.

Comment: Fair enough, yeah.  I'll go ahead and fix that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$lines = file('http://www.example.com/');//or local file

unset($lines[0]);
unset($lines[count($lines)-1)]);
$new_file = implode('', $lines); //may want to use line break "\n" for the join
```

Comment: what if there was only one line or none?

Comment: well the question said skip first and last *line*, so i can only assume there is more than 3 - i have nothing more to go on than that which was asked

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try exploding the file contents. It will help you alot! After that you will label it.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, file() will open file into "serial" stream (not sure if serial is right word), it means that you must read full file before detecting his end

Comment: Its true that its a stream, but it is completely untrue that you don't know where the end of file is and that you must read whole file. `$fp = fopen($path, 'r'); fseek($fp, -16); $end = fgets($fp);` should return last 16 bytes of file (if it is at least 16 bytes) without reading whole contents.

Comment: second thing is that `file` function is not opening file as a stream - it reads its contents for you and return as an `array` of lines.

Comment: My answer was relate to question, i'm not telling, that there is no way to get the characters at the end of file, but no way to skip last line of the end without reading file. If you will peek last 16 bytes, that will not skip that last bytes..., so you must read full file and then skip his last line. Or there is other way?

Comment: Oh, your right about file() ..., i'm confused that function with fopen

Comment: And now looking on function file(), it's comming other answer about how to do this just: array_pop(array_shift(file("YourFile")))

Comment: `array_shift` will return first element of array returned by `file` and this way you would generate `only variables can be passed by reference`. right would be `array_slice(file($path), 1, -1)`

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 $str= file_get_contents("file.txt");
 $arr = preg_split ("\n",$str);
 $n = count($arr);
```

$n is a number of lines

```
$str="";
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
   if($i>0 && $i<($n-1)){ $str.=$arr[$i]}
   }
    /**Str without line 1 and final line */
```