# Extract certificate from file to string with PHP

Tags: php

I'm new for PHP and I have certificate file like this:

**cert.pem** file content:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIID3zCCAsegAwIBAgIJAKeRq8Dl6HE3MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGFMQswCQYD
VQQGEwJFRTETMBEGA1UECAwKU29tZS1TdGF0ZTEOMAwGA1UEBwwFVGFydHUxDjAM
BgNVBAoMBUhJVFNBMQ4wDAYDVQQLDAVFRU5ldDETMBEGA1UEAwwKc2VydmVyLmNv
bTEcMBoGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYNc3ZodUBlZW5ldC5lZTAeFw0xNjAzMjgxMjQ2NDBa
Fw0xNjA0MjcxMjQ2NDBaMIGFMQswCQYDVQQGEwJFRTETMBEGA1UECAwKU29tZS1T
dGF0ZTEOMAwGA1UEBwwFVGFydHUxDjAMBgNVBAoMBUhJVFNBMQ4wDAYDVQQLDAVF
RU5ldDETMBEGA1UEAwwKc2VydmVyLmNvbTEcMBoGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYNc3ZodUBl
ZW5ldC5lZTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBALAzpCCn9aID
ByqSzI5BaDVznFnMAll0OGKbdiqNWI0ClvOMc+faRP1Bnd39WiMvVXZ5Yew04iwm
OjSj2uzM+1hZfnxdZLKD/gJZZIoZP8Yrc5urqI87GFPEsrqBfmKr8vC9Pvt5WPcV
F4LObLiSSo8QT98o6llxIVYqPpMQOL2LRDL4FvJ/wQFVg4SRtZPPLmI6z1Tp3QwR
D7//D3eJKeJsP4ZTJllmTxGMnW+05WIEF6HP7kjwoWUe/LXly221ecWbAy6vZHVF
n6WZPh8D14mXJuzbr1K+isG9P5au3A2dZWYgvdW5V6GbeFMLgR+o0WzEUbUI77eo
U2ZhQZB2zFsCAwEAAaNQME4wHQYDVR0OBBYEFBJ5ATknaTeHbRX3YsZwbJbqoefG
MB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFBJ5ATknaTeHbRX3YsZwbJbqoefGMAwGA1UdEwQFMAMBAf8w
DQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBABUFAm72zOs0sKZF8b4gwbH1Jrru6922dyblxIAb
/GyZMgTejqLl9f1UKx25Zja8RCbyQF155a24I0pxupWW5LJNTUWKaOtkQqfXMcF4
pm6suVLZRanAcAJrt9nUWdzYortQKYNjWXLSj4ffz7wNvBcWLaJTsp0AgF9+tOBD
8jZNoeg05QRTDLvNRVyH41JTxQ0q0Fd8mryX4OSS7FtyJ8wHW+befJ7gf0UprjVC
7WqBHiCab5viv6QQqr6HnbQNvXex+q4nOV1dSH9vaun7ozsgSzXgKHohkz1K15wT
L2S3kChZ+Un47xRTxeaGudmO4kueX4q3DTYN2+nWRpPkHwI=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I'd like to merge all lines between `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` in single line without line breaks. Like this:

> $cert = "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"

Comment: Are you looking for [skip first and last line of a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637069/php-skip-first-and-last-line-of-a-text-file-using-fgets)

Comment: Not exactly.. it will break if cert file ends with empty line and it doesn't teach how to merge rest of the lines.

Comment: @Rizier123 Please remove duplicate sign because I'd like to add my own solution which isn't related to question you are refering to.

Comment: Finally I managed to get it to work like this:

$path = 'path/to/cert/file.crt';
$content = file_get_contents($path);

function extract_certificate($content)
{
  // Remove line breaks and beginning and end string
  return str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----", "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" ), '', $content);
}
$certificate = extract_certificate($content);

Comment: The duplicate does answer your question. And your solution is a very specific one just for this specfic case.